# JS - GET .php file on webserver gives 404

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, get, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load some data from a MySQL database into an HTML website. My approach at the moment is a PHP script that returns the database data as JSON and then a JS script that uses this data for creating the HTML elements.

All is being hosted on a webserver, and currently with all files in the same directory. When running I receive the following error:

`GET http://www.<website>.com/fetch_data.php 404 (Not Found)`

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
// Create a connection to the database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check if the connection was successful
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Construct the SQL query to retrieve player data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players";

// Execute the SQL query and store the result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if any rows were returned
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $players = array();
  // Loop through each row and store the player data in an array
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $player = array(
      "name" => $row["name"],
      "description" => $row["description"],
      "hcp" => $row["hcp"],
      "image" => $row["image"]
    );
    array_push($players, $player);
  }
  // Encode the array as JSON and return it
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($players);
} else {
  echo "No players found";
}

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

And this is my JS script that I include in my HTML:

```
// Container reference
const gridContainer = document.querySelector(".grid-container");

// Fetch the data from the database
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "./fetch_data.php");
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // Loop through the data and create a grid item for each player
    data.forEach(player => {
      const gridItem = document.createElement("div");
      gridItem.classList.add("grid-item");
      gridItem.innerHTML = `
        <div class="top-wrapper">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="pics/${player.image}" alt="${player.name}">
          </div>
          <div class="info-wrapper">
            <h2>${player.name}</h2>
            <p>${player.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stats-wrapper">
          <div class="stats-item">
            <h3>HCP</h3>
            <p>#${player.hcp}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" placeholder="???"/>
          <button class="input-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
        </div>
      `;
      gridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
    });
  } else {
    console.error(xhr.statusText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Any help is appreciated - feel free to give input on my approach as well.

Comment: "_Not Found_" is all we can tell you, check the URL of the request. You can see the full URL of the request at Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: @Teemu the Request URL is shown as `http://www.<website>.com/fetch_data.php` in the Network tab (redacted website name). So it seems like it can't find my .php file?

Comment: The file obviously doesn't exist at the given URL. According to the address, it should be located on the same folder as the page calling it is located.

Comment: But that's my problem, because it does. If I go to the file manager of my domain, I can see the file there.

Comment: Might be an issue with your webserver (nginx/apache) config. Can you open this file directly? With no ajax? Can you open any .php file?

Comment: @konrados If I try to access `http://www.<website>.com/fetch_data.php` directly I get a HTTP Error 404.3. It mentions Handlers, MIME and IIS as potential fixes, but I don't have any knowledge of this.

Comment: @bragi - you wrote "I get a HTTP Error 404.3. " - Now I'm not sure if this is 404 or 403. If the latter, that might suggest file permissions problem, if the first one (404) - then there are only two options, the file just isn't there (maybe a typo?) or something is wrong in the nginx/apache/whatever config.

You might want to update your question and add your webserver configuration (assuming it is not simply a typo in file name)

Comment: @bragi, sorry, I missed the "IIS" part, then well, I can't help you with this, except giving a little advice,  that you need to read about this stuff anyway, sooner or later (MIME, "handlers", permissions). Plus - you might want to ask on #IIS I guess.

Comment: www is a subdomain, does it really exist? I guess just dropping www from the address makes your code to work.